# Error on tensorflow: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul_25'

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to create a conditional GAN. However, i'm stuck as to why no matter what i do, it appears the same error over and over again. 
Here's the code:

```
image_dim = 784  #28 * 28
Y_dimension = 10
gen_hidd_dim = 256
disc_hidd_dim = 256
z_noise_dim =100 #input noise datapoint

def xavier_init(shape):
  return tf.random_normal(shape = shape, stddev = 1/tf.sqrt(shape[0]/2.0))

weights = {
    'disc_H' : tf.Variable(xavier_init([image_dim + Y_dimension, disc_hidd_dim])),
    'disc_final' : tf.Variable(xavier_init([disc_hidd_dim, 1])),
    'gen_H': tf.Variable([z_noise_dim + Y_dimension, gen_hidd_dim]),
    'gen_final': tf.Variable(xavier_init([gen_hidd_dim, image_dim]))
}

bias = {
    'disc_H': tf.Variable(xavier_init([disc_hidd_dim])),
    'disc_final': tf.Variable(xavier_init([1])),
    'gen_H': tf.Variable(xavier_init([gen_hidd_dim])),
    'gen_final': tf.Variable(xavier_init([image_dim]))
}

Z_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape= [None, z_noise_dim ], name = 'input_noise')
Y_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape= [None, Y_dimension], name='Labels')
X_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, image_dim], name = 'real_input')

def Discriminator(x,y):
  inputs = tf.concat(axis = 1, values = [x,y])
  hidden_layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(inputs, weights['disc_H']), bias['disc_H']))
  final_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_layer, weights['disc_final']), bias['disc_final'])
  disc_output = tf.nn.sigmoid(final_layer)
  return final_layer, disc_output

def Generator(x,y):
  inputs = tf.concat(axis=1, values=[x,y])
  hidden_layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(tf.cast(inputs, tf.float32), tf.cast(weights['gen_H'], tf.float32)), tf.cast(bias['gen_H'],tf.float32)))
  final_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_layer, weights['gen_final']), bias['gen_final'])
  gen_output = tf.nn.sigmoid(final_layer)
  return gen_output

output_Gen = Generator(Z_input, Y_input)
```

Right after executing the Generator i get the following error:

```
 ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul_25' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,110], [2].
```

What to do?

Comment: Check weights and hidden_layer shapes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just missed one call to `xavier_init()` when initialising your weights.

You have this:

```
weights = {
    'disc_H' : tf.Variable(xavier_init([image_dim + Y_dimension, disc_hidd_dim])),
    'disc_final' : tf.Variable(xavier_init([disc_hidd_dim, 1])),
    'gen_H': tf.Variable([z_noise_dim + Y_dimension, gen_hidd_dim]),
    'gen_final': tf.Variable(xavier_init([gen_hidd_dim, image_dim]))
}
```

but I think you want this:

```
weights = {
    'disc_H' : tf.Variable(xavier_init([image_dim + Y_dimension, disc_hidd_dim])),
    'disc_final' : tf.Variable(xavier_init([disc_hidd_dim, 1])),
    'gen_H': tf.Variable(xavier_init([z_noise_dim + Y_dimension, gen_hidd_dim])),
    'gen_final': tf.Variable(xavier_init([gen_hidd_dim, image_dim]))
}
```

The error message was because `weights['gen_H']` had shape `[2]` whereas you expected it to have shape `[110, 256]`. This meant that the call to `tf.matmul()` failed because it's impossible to matrix multiply a matrix with shape `[m, 110]` by a matrix of shape `[2]`